# onPageFinished() never called (webview)!

Tags: android, load, webview, toast

I want to show a toast when the webview is totally loaded. But the toast never show up, i don't know why..here is my code:

```
public class WebViewSignUp extends Activity{

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webviewsignup);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.home)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            } 
         });

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://pabebbe.com/m/register");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The second call to `setWebViewClient()` is overwriting the first.

Create only a single instance of `WebViewClient` with both overrides in the same class, and call `setWebViewClient` only once.  Then load the Webview:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
mWebView.loadUrl("http://pabebbe.com/m/register");
```

Comment: onPageFinished is never called for some urls, I tried waiting for a long time.
It totally depends on "what's going on the webpage"...!

Answer (score 0):

@mportuesisf is 100% correct, also note in the callback you're calling the wrong webview's onPageFinished. This might be relevant if you have multiple webviews using the client. I would fix:

```
super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
```

to

```
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```