# How can i add app header in cordova inappbrowser

Tags: wordpress, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, json-api

i'm new to ionic app development i'm developing a app which uses WordPress json api to retrieve information from WordPress site and display it in app.In mobile the external links are handled by Cordova InAppBrowser i want to include the app header bar in cordova inappbrowser and also i want to know other methods of handling external link in api.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the WebChromeClient method to achieve your task as:
[What's the difference between setWebViewClient vs. setWebChromeClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835556/whats-the-difference-between-setwebviewclient-vs-setwebchromeclient)

Comment: create inner class in **MainActivity** having loadUrl declaration for instance: **class InnerClass extends WebChromeClient{  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //do some code} }**

Comment: You can also refer:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719814/onpagefinished-never-called-webview)