# When or from Where should we add listener to body in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, webview, dom-events, android-webview

From where exactly should we try to add a listener to body (or any other tag) tag using JS in Android webview.

Because in `onPageStarted()` the element might not have been loaded and in `onPageFinished()` the element might have already completed loading.

Answer (score 0):

You know that [onPageFinished()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719814/onpagefinished-never-called-webview%20and%20https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member) and [onPageStarted](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebViewClient.OnPageStarted/p/Android.Webkit.WebView/System.String/Android.Graphics.Bitmap/)() are android methodes and not JS methodes. If you want to use JS that only is excuted when your page is load you need to do something like this:

```
var init = function () {
    DoSomeFunction();
};

$(document).ready(init());
```

Comment: so jquerys ready gets executed only when all the resources are loaded? Does it include complete loading of a script added using the cdn url (mathjax)?

Comment: Are you using a cdn in webview your not loading it local mathJax? the init will only be excuted when the webpage is completely loaded.