# WebView - only show back button if back history exists

Tags: java, android, webview

I developed a simple webview app. I added a button which should act as the back button, so users can navigate back one page.

The button is initially hidden and should only show if a back history exists.
How can I realise this?

The code is simple:

```
backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
backButton.setEnabled(blizzView.canGoBack());
```

but where do I have to call this? How is the "some site loaded" event called?

**Update:**

I tried to apply @Murats answer, but nothing happens:

```
private WebView blizzView;  // my webview
private Button backButton;

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
    backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setEnabled(blizzView.canGoBack());

    if (blizzView.canGoBack()) {
        backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: To clarify: you have a WebView, and you have a Button. You want the button click event to navigate the WebView back one page but only if there is navigation history in the WebView, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. If there is no back history, then the button should be invisible and disabled.

Comment: the why u accepted the answer?

Comment: Because it leaded me to the solution and I can accept mine only in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this:

```
blizzView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      //
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setEnabled(blizzView.canGoBack());

        if (blizzView.canGoBack()) {
            backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            backButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`WebView#canGoBack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack()) to find out if there is a backstack. You can check for that after the page is loaded e.g. in [`WebViewClient#onPageFinished`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%2520java.lang.String))

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it!  Yes, this would a correct solution.

Comment: @Murat, I tried it and updated my question with my attempt. Does not work.

Comment: @Black That is not how you use the method.. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719814/onpagefinished-never-called-webview

Comment: @Black You have to override the `onPageFinished` in the `WebViewClient`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thx :)